# Run time error while using realloc: " _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData), dbgheap.c"

Tags: c++

The following code is written in C++ but using realloc from stdlib.h because I don't know much about std::vector.

Anyway, I get this weird run time error " " _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData), dbgheap.c".

If you would like to see the whole method or code please let me know.

I have 2 classes, Student and Grades. Student contains

```
char _name[21];         
char _id[6];             

int _numOfGrades;
int* _grades;
float _avg;
```

and Grade simply contains

```
Student* _students;
int _numOfStudents;
```

while the following works

`_grades = (int *)realloc(_grades,(sizeof(int)*(_numOfGrades+1)));`

this will create that weird run time error:

```
_students = (Student *)realloc(_students,(sizeof(Student)*(_numOfStudents+1)));
```

Both _grades and _students are created with new with no problem at all. The problem is only while trying to realloc _students.

Any input will be welcome.

Comment: is it possible that you have a memory leak somewhere, maybe in code that is not related to this? Looks like corrupted memory heap. For example, if you write outside the allocated space for the previous allocation of grades, this can happen.

Comment: You said a Grade has 2 members, but when you allocate memory you only allocate space for one (int) member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix allocators—if you allocate memory with `operator new[]`, you **must** deallocate it with `operator delete[]`.  You cannot use `free()`, `realloc()`, or any other memory allocator (e.g. Windows' `GlobalFree()`/`LocalFree()`/`HeapFree()` functions).

`realloc()` can only reallocate memory regions which were allocated with the `malloc()` family of functions (`malloc()`, `calloc()`, and `realloc()`).  Attempting to `realloc` any other memory block is undefined behavior—in this case, you got lucky and the C runtime was able to catch your error, but if you were unlucky, you might silently corrupt memory and then later crash at some random point in an "impossible" state.

Comment: Thanks alot, though I have no problem in using realloc() after using new with _grades. Is it expected to work "randomly" and should be avoided?

Comment: Well... I just changed the original allocation for _students to malloc instead of new and what do you know, it works :)  It's funny though, because there was no problem using new with realloc for _grades...

Anyway, thanks a lot :).